# In a group, take two elements a, b s.t. ab=ba. o(a) is relatively prime to o(b) (the orders of a and b) show o(ab) =o(a)o(b)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$ show that for two elements $a,b \in G$ such that

1. $ab=ba$ ($a$ & $b$ commute)
2. $o(a) \perp o(b)$ (their orders are relatively prime)

show that $o(ab) = o(a)o(b)$.

Let:

$o(a)=k$,  $o(b)=l$,  $o(ab)=m$
$a^n=e$, $b^p=e,$ $(ab)^q=e$
This implies $k|n$, $l|p$, $m|q$
$n=uk$ for an integer $u$
$p=sl$  for an integer $s$
$q=tm$   for an integer $t$
$np=us(kl)$ 
So if I know $m=lk$ $np$ must $=q$ so how do I show $np=q$ so I can say $m=lk$?

Comment: In other words, the quotient maps induce an isomorphism $\mathbb Z/(kl) \to \mathbb Z /(k) \times \mathbb Z /(l)$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The maps $\mathbb Z \to G$ sending the generator to $a$ and $b$ respectively induce a group homomorphism $\mathbb Z/(k) \times \mathbb Z/(l) \to G$. This map is an isomorphism onto the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$ and $b$ (this needs proof as well). The element $(\bar 1, \bar 1)$ is mapped to $ab$. Now, the quotient maps $\mathbb Z/(kl) \to \mathbb Z/(k)$ and $\mathbb Z/(kl) \to \mathbb Z/(l)$ induce a map $\mathbb Z/(kl) \to \mathbb Z/(k) \times \mathbb Z/(l)$ which sends the generator to $(\bar 1, \bar 1)$. Thus, if we see that this map is an isomorphism, then the order of $ab$ is $kl$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first use the commutativity property to show that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ (use recursion). Then I'd show that $\forall j, k \in N$ we have $a^jb^k=e$ iff $a^j=b^k=e$. (Proof by contradiction is probably the easiest. You will also use the fact that if $\langle{a}\rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle{b}\rangle$ then $o(a)|o(b)$)

Once we have these two tools we know that the order of $(ab)$ is the smallest $n \in N$ such that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n = e$. This is only true if $a^n = b^n = e$ which in turn means that $o(a)|n$ and $o(b)|n$. Given that we want the smallest $n$ this gives us $n=LCM(o(a),o(b))$ and because $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are relatively prime this means that $n=o(a)o(b)$.